# Why npm installed lots of unexpected modules?

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-install

I'm using laravel-5.1,with this `package.json`

`{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}`

under root directory,I use `npm install` command under project root to install `laravel-elixir` and `bootstrap-sass`.
After npm installation finished, I found there were more than 30 node modules under my node_modules diretory,and lots of .cmd files under project root!
Now I have used git to rollback my project,how to install `laravel-elixir` and `bootstrap-sass` correctly using `npm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each dependency may depend it self on other dependencies and so one.

For example if you want to install a single dependency you may end up with **10 or more dependencies**.

Another example is when you install [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) you end up with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) installed also because Bootstrap depends on jQuery.

Comment: Is there any way to install dependencies to another position,or installed dependencies globally?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this.
Do you want to install the dependencies of your current project globally ?

Comment: The first thing I want to avoid,is there are so many .cmd files under my project root directory after npm installation finished,I think there must be something wrong.

Comment: Yes, all node modules should be installed inside ``node_modules`` directory when using ``npm install``  and not directly to your root directory.

Comment: thanks! And did you mean the .cmd files downloaded by npm are necessary too?

Comment: May be some modules provide ``.cmd`` files but they should be installed under  ``node_modules\dependency-name\file-name.cmd``.

Comment: @nick If you find this a useful answer please consider hitting that Up-vote arrow !

Answer (score 0):

These dependencies might require other dependencies, so it will install them aswell.