# npm install appears to be installing too much

Tags: npm

Newbie question

I am trying to reduce the size of an app in order to share on GitHub.

When I delete node_modules folder and run npm install I get a new node_modules folder containing 626 subfolders with size 226Mb.

I had thought npm install only intalled those dependencies specified in package.json.

I have tried running npm prune bot it doesn't do anything.

Here is the package.json in case it helps.

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.myApp",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.1.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"app/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.3",
    "nativescript-angular": "~7.2.0",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.0.2",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^4.0.1",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^6.0.4",
    "nativescript-modal-datetimepicker": "^1.1.4",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-toast": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^5.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^5.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~7.3.0",
    "babel-traverse": "6.26.0",
    "babel-types": "6.26.0",
    "babylon": "6.18.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "~1.0.1",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "~4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "~2.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.2",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.6.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.7.3",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.19.1",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.9.0",
    "raw-loader": "~1.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "~3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "~7.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.1",
    "typescript": "~3.3.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "~2.1.1",
    "webpack": "~4.29.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "~3.0.3",
    "webpack-cli": "~3.2.3",
    "webpack-sources": "~1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: npm installs your dependencies and the dependencies of the dependencies and so on (recursively). So you may need to cut out some bigger dependencies if you want to reduce size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why npm installed lots of unexpected modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325883/why-npm-installed-lots-of-unexpected-modules)

Comment: Ok thanks I am going to have to read up on reducing the final size.

Comment: For example, it looks like you dont need  "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.3" for running your app, so put it in <devdependencies>. 

Some things you can try in your build-to-prod process:
- keep in mind to have in dependencies only those packages you need to RUN the app, not to debug, test, typings, etc.
- run --> npm prune --production  (to remove packages in devdependencies and keep only dependencies)
- run --> npm dedupe (to flatten the node_modules folders, moving repeated packages into the most outer node_modules)